# Send mulipart/form-data request in Android

Tags: java, android, rest, jersey, multipartform-data

I am currently creating a Android app but I encountered an issue.
I created the backend part (hosted on a server) with Java and Jersey.

All my web services are POST and return a JSON string and almost all of them require only strings but several of them need also to receive a file.

- When I call the web services with Google Postman, everything works fine.
- When I send a POST request from my Android project to a php file that I created (for another project), it also works fine.

But when I try to send requests to my web services, I get errors launching the Android app. The response code are either 415 or 500 depending on the content type.

*My question is, how should I set the content types on both side to send post requests from Android to my server and get a JSON String ?* I need to add that I also sometimes need to send files via the POST request.

This is what I have in my Java Code

```
@POST
@Path("/login")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")

public String getLogin(@FormDataParam("mail") String mail,
        @FormDataParam("pwd") String pwd){ ...
```

And this is what I have in my Android code

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod(p.getMethod());
con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `Content-Type` on both sides to `application/json`. That is, if you're sending a JSON string to the server. If the files you are sending are text files, use `application/text`. Otherwise, look [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html) for info on the correct `Content-Type` for different file formats.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, I programmed the server so that the values I expect as an input are a list of keys and values. Exactly like in a GET request, where you add (key,value) couples. My question was how to send this type of data to the Java server

Answer (score 0):

Trying to format a multipart request is not a trivial task if you don't know what you are doing. You can see the [W3C documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) for a sample format and some explanation

```
   Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x

   --AaB03x
   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit-name"

   Larry
   --AaB03x
   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="file1.txt"
   Content-Type: text/plain

   ... contents of file1.txt ...
   --AaB03x--
```

That's pretty much what the body (and Content-Type header) should look like when you make the request. I've made simple helper class, that works for simple String and file cases. It didn't take me too long to make and I haven't battle tested it, but it works for simple use cases. Personally I would probably do some refactoring, but it'll give you a starting point.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MultipartHelper {

    public String contentType;
    public String boundary;
    public HttpURLConnection connection;

    private final List<FilePart> fileParts = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<StringPart> stringParts = new ArrayList<>();

    public MultipartHelper(HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException {
        this(connection, "multipart/form-data");
    }

    public MultipartHelper(HttpURLConnection connection, String contentType) throws IOException {
        this.boundary = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        this.connection = connection;
        contentType = contentType == null? "multipart/form-data": contentType;
        contentType += "; boundary=" + boundary;

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);
    }

    public void addStringPart(String data, String name) {
        stringParts.add(new StringPart(data, name));
    }

    public void addFilePart(File file, String contentType, String name) {
        if (contentType == null) {
            contentType = "application/octet-stream";
        }
        fileParts.add(new FilePart(file, contentType, name));
    }

    public void makeRequest() {
        Writer writer = null;
        try {
            OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));

            for (StringPart sp: stringParts) {
                writer.write("--" + boundary + "\r\n");
                writer.write("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=" + sp.name + "\r\n");
                writer.write("Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n");
                writer.write(sp.data + "\r\n");
            }
            writer.flush();

            InputStream in = null;
            for (FilePart fp: fileParts) {
                writer.write("--" + boundary + "\r\n");
                writer.write("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=" 
                        + fp.name + "; filename=" + fp.file.getName() + "\r\n");
                writer.write("Content-Type: " + fp.contentType + "\r\n\r\n");
                writer.flush();

                in = new FileInputStream(fp.file);
                int count;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                while ((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
                out.flush();
                writer.write("\r\n");
                writer.flush();

                in.close();
            }
            writer.write("--" + boundary + "--\r\r");
            writer.flush();
            out.close();
            writer.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class StringPart {
        String data;
        String name;
        public StringPart(String data, String name) {
            this.data = data;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    class FilePart {
        File file;
        String name;
        String contentType;
        public FilePart(File file, String contentType, String name) {
            this.file = file;
            this.name = name;
            this.contentType = contentType;
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage

```
final String urlStr = "http://localhost:8080/api/upload";
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(
        new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8888)));
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

MultipartHelper multipart = new MultipartHelper(connection);
multipart.addStringPart("Hello Part 1", "string1");
multipart.addFilePart(new File("stackoverflow.png"), "image/png", "image");

multipart.makeRequest();
```

Me personally though, I would go with a library that already has this feature. For example [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) has multipart support. It is a pretty popular rest client library. Here's an example

You first need the dependency

Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit</groupId>
    <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
```

First you need an interface for the client service

```
import retrofit.http.Multipart;
import retrofit.http.POST;
import retrofit.http.Part;
import retrofit.mime.TypedFile;
import retrofit.mime.TypedString;

public interface UploadService {

    @Multipart
    @POST("/upload")
    retrofit.client.Response upload(@Part("image") TypedFile image, 
                                    @Part("string1") TypedString string1);
}
```

Then make the request like

```
RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
        .setEndpoint("http://localhost:8080/api")
        .build();

UploadService service = adapter.create(UploadService.class);
TypedFile file = new TypedFile("image/png", new File("stackoverflow.png"));
TypedString str = new TypedString("Hello World");

retrofit.client.Response response = service.upload(file, str);
```